# Microsoft Power BI free connector to HBase

Tags: hbase, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Is there a free way of connecting Power BI to HBase?

I can connect using ODBC/ADO.Net HBase driver which is offered by CData Software but I was wondering if it's possible to connect using any free driver.

May be it's possible to use some framework or SDK for this goal in PBI?